# C# word document clone existing word file as a new document

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I want to create application to fill template documents automated by C# Interop.Word library. User chooses template document from existing files. I have to clone this document to the new document (including padding, margin and all the format).

1.I have tried to use InsertFile function

```
document = app.Documents.Add();
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object start = 0;
object end = 0;
Word.Range range = document.Range(ref start, ref end);
range.InsertFile(template_file_name, ref missing, ref _true, ref missing, ref missing);
```

and filling template inside document. But this function changes some of the formats from template

---

2. I have tried using Copy and PasteSpecial

```
app=new Word.Application();
src_doc=app.Documents.Open(template_file_name);
document=app.Documents.Add();
src_doc.Content.Copy();
document.Content.PasteSpecial(DataType:Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
```

This code keeps format correct. But after pasting it is problematic to change value. "src_doc" keeps open even after closing it.

> Long story short. Need to clone existing document as a new Document

Comment: I'm no expert but can't you just copy this as a file? Rather than trying to clone a word document, you could just use System.IO and create a copy of this file on the disk and open that using Interop? Apologies if this doesn't apply to your requirement.

Comment: This solution works. but it opens the document as existing file. I need to open it as new document (so that user can save it to anywhere).

Comment: There's another idea here - create your template as a `.dotm` template and open word using your template as an argument on the command line.
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\Winword.exe" /t"C:\Users\me\Documents\Custom Office Templates\myTemplate.dotm"` This should accomplish what you're trying if it is possible to create your template as a Work Template format.

Comment: Is it possible to open `.docx` instead of `.dotm` as a template

Comment: Use Documents.Add(templateFilePath) to create a new docx from a dotm or dotx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by passing a file path to the Docments.Add method:

```
Word.Application _word = new Word.Application();
_word.Visible = true;
_word.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;

Word.Document _doc = _word.Documents.Add(pathToExistingDocument);
```